# filter array of objects with underscore and get new array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I do have an array of objects and I want to create a filter function to return an new array

```
var items = [{
        "row": 0,
        "column": 0,
        "items": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    }, {
        "row": 0,
        "column": 1,
        "items": [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
            ....



        {
            "row": 2,
            "column": 2,
            "items": [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
        }]

    var newArray = function (items, row) {
        //filter items and return new array

        return filtered
    }
```

newArray should contain all values from 'items' that have the same row value.

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow. It would help if you explained what you have tried so far and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Tried to group them with var rowGrps = _.groupBy(items, function(p){ 
    return p.row;
}); but didn't feel right

Comment: Could you demonstrate the result you're expecting to be created from this?

Comment: @lunacafu: But that's just what you want? How else should the expected output look like? Btw, you could shorten that to `_.groupBy(items, "row")`

Comment: Question is confusing because the top-level array is called `items`, but also each item contains a property named `items`

Comment: Also, "contain all items that have the same row value" is ambiguous.  What does that mean?  Should only return items that share a row value with at least one other item?  Should only return items that match a particular row value?  or Should only return items where the row value matches the array index in items (as I assumed in my answer below)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: Ah, I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the result would be given by

```
function filter(items, row) {
    return _.chain(items)    // initiate method chaining for convenience
        .where({row: row})   // filter out objects from rows we don't care about
        .pluck("items")      // get the "items" arrays from the filtered objects
        .flatten()           // concatenate them into a single array
        .value();            // unwrap the result to return it
}
```

Calling `filter(items, 0)` in the example given would return

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

which is the concatenated aggregate of `items` arrays inside objects with `row` equal to 0.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, it returns a plain array with all the items values from all objects that match row id

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for this:

```
_.reduce(items, function(res, item) {
    var key = item.row;
    if (!(key in res)) res[key] = [];
    [].push.apply(res[key], item.items);
    return res;
}, {})
```

Comment: also feasible, returns an object with all items as separate arrays

Answer (score 1):

In underscore, to get all items where the row value matches the index of the item in the array:

```
var items = [...];
var filteredItems = _.filter(items, function(item, i) {
  return item.row == i;
});
```

Or with the native Array.prototype.map method.  E.g.

```
var items = [...];
var filteredItems = items.filter(function(item, i) {
  return item.row == i;
});
```

Comment: the result I receive contains only the first object with row 0

Comment: Of course, since this does only return items whose `row` value is the same as their index in the `items` array…